# Is this java classpath set correctly?

Tags: java, swing

I really have no idea what I'm missing. I've spent many hours reading up on how to set classpaths but this still does not work, at this point I am convinced it must be something trivial which escapes me.

I'm trying to use the swing [radiance libraries](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance) to change the look and feel of a swing application. I followed the [build documentation](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance/blob/master/docs/building.md) to make the jar files and when those didn't work I downloaded and tried the [prebuilt binaries](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance/tree/master/drop/2.5-SNAPSHOT/core). I opened an issue with developer and confirmed I was following the [getting started instructions](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance/blob/master/docs/substance/getting-started.md) correctly. The code for demonstration is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Walkthrough extends JFrame {
  public Walkthrough() {
    super("Sample app");
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(new JButton("button"));
    this.add(new JCheckBox("check"));
    this.add(new JLabel("label"));

    this.setIconImage(new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR));
    this.setSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        Walkthrough w = new Walkthrough();
        w.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

The code is first compiled with `javac Walkthrough.java` and executed with `java Walkthrough`. This works fine. Next the radiance jars are used to change the look and feel, this is done by setting the `swing.defaultlaf` property to use a skin from radiance. This is where it does not work.

I copied all the required jars into a `tmp` directory, where the Walkthrough example exists immediately outside of `tmp`. I then try to run the application as follows:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel -cp .:tmp/radiance-substance-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:tmp/radiance-trident-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:tmp/radiance-neon-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar Walkthrough
```

Which leads to the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot load org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1406)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1517)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1483)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1056)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.createGlassPane(JRootPane.java:521)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:348)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:279)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:225)
    at Walkthrough.<init>(Walkthrough.java:7)
    at Walkthrough.lambda$main$0(Walkthrough.java:23)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel lives in radiance-substance-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar. I have confirmed it is indeed there with `jar tvf`:

```
jar tvf radiance-substance-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel
   548 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT 1980 org/pushingpixels/substance/api/skin/SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel.class
```

**So at this point I'm sure that I'm messing something up with the classpath**, but I just don't know what. I'm on Fedora 28 and my java version is:

```
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: My guess is that you should downgrade your Java version for now. Try with Java 9 as per the official docs, then work your way up.

Comment: @steven35 I contacted the developer about this, java 9 is only required to build the library, but it works with java 9 and onward. He also confirmed he tried the steps under java 12 and it worked for him.

Comment: If you are not using an IDE, are you specifying the classpath via the `-cp` argument when you are running it?

Comment: @steven35 Yep, I do so via: ```java -Dswing.defaultlaf=org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel -cp .:tmp/radiance-substance-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:tmp/radiance-trident-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:tmp/radiance-neon-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar Walkthrough```

Comment: Is your project modular? If it is then are you requiring the module in the module descriptor (module-info.class)?

Comment: Nevermind, the radiance lib isn't modular.

Comment: You can use a wildcard to include all jars in a directory to the classpath. `java -cp .:./tmp/* ...`. Maybe give that a try just in case there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: As a second thing to try, you can [programmatically set the look and feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic). Doing so might give you a more descriptive exception with an actual root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this had nothing to do with the classpath and rather to do with the jar libraries themselves. I observed that the font was not anti-aliased by default on my machine (Fedora 28, using i3-gaps as a window manager). I wondered if this was somehow related and did some reading on Java runtime environment fonts. In essence the fonts looked like this:

[image]

But launching the application with this system property: `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` fixed things:

[image]

It turns out that setting this property when launching Walkthrough with Radiance makes it work:

`java -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.defaultlaf=org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel -cp .:tmp/radiance-substance-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:tmp/radiance-trident-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:tmp/radiance-neon-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar Walkthrough`.

[image]

Removing this property results in the error of Java being unable to load org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceBusinessLookAndFeel.

Reading [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts) has more information. I **assume** because I have customised my Fedora 28 setup (I don't use gnome) is the reason I don't have an `gnome-settings-daemon` running from which Java uses to get the system defaults and this is somehow a problem for Radiance...? Not sure.

I've informed the Radiance developer about this. I'll update this answer if/when he provides feedback.

**UPDATE**
The developer confirmed this has a bug in the library. It has been fixed.

Comment: Good stuff. Can you still do my suggestion of loading the look and feel programmatically to see if that produces a more informative exception?

Comment: @Gimby yes I did try this, thanks; but this time I was able to catch the exception and print its stack trace. I've passed this information on to the developer.